# Frame number right of presentation controls

Tags: beamer, numbering, navigation, header-footer

I currently use

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
```

to get frame numbers on my slides produced by the LaTeX beamer class. But the presentation controls are above them and not on the left and thus taking too much space of the slides. How can I get both the controls and the frame number in one line?

For illustration purposes a little code example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to give us a small but complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, just tried to upload an image of a sample slide, but I couldn't as I have less than 10 rep. :(

Comment: Images aren't very helpful, code examples are usually the best way to show a problem. For instance, we don't know the beamer theme you're using.

Comment: Okay, added code example.

Comment: Good to have something to work with, I will write a suggestion. Btw. in such a minimal example you could omit unnecessary packages. And here's a conflict with the options `dvips` and `pdftex`.

Comment: Glad, you told me! Thanks! I'm just a LaTeX beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the default theme, like your code example does, this is a solution:

```
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
\hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}
```

The first line removes the right sidebar because originally the navigation symbols appear in that sidebar. I would like to use it in the footline instead together with the frame numbering.
The next lines do exactly that: printing out the navigation symbols in grey (without the *** you would get mixed black and grey symbols) and next to it some space followed by current and total frame number.